# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"payments", :company_id=>#<Company id: 1 etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So, I added the edit function to my payments controller, like this:

```
 def edit

   @payment = Payment.edit
     if @payment.save
       redirect_to showCompany_path, notice: 'Successfully edited!'
     else
       render :edit
     end
   end
```

I have a corresponding edit.html.haml view in my payments/view.
This is my routes rb:

```
resources :companies do
   put :edit, :on => :collection

   resources :payments do
     put :edit, :on => :collection
   end
end
```

And I want to have a link to this payments edit in my other view, which I defined like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Payment Info', edit_company_payment_path(company), {:style=>'color:black; display:inline;', :class=>"btn btn-primary" }  %>
```

I think I have done everything I should, but still I get this error from the title. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate a url to companies/:company_id/payments/:payment_id, Rails needs to know th e payment as well.
In other words, you are missing the payment param:

```
edit_company_payment_path(company, payment)
```

Comment: When I put edit_company_payment_path(company, payment), I get: undefined local variable payment, and when I put edit_company_payment_path(company, @payment), I get the same error I began with.

Comment: is @payment a payment? Or is it nil?

Comment: I think it is nil.. I don't think I even have payment id at all.

Comment: So you want to link to an edit page for a payment which you don't have?

Comment: Ah wait, you created a custom route for edit (for PUT). If you do resources :payments, it will create an edit route for members in your collection. It seems that they are conflicting. BTW, Even if you get the link to /companies/123/payment/edit to work, it will raise errors because clicking a link does a 'GET' and you defined a 'PUT'. I would strongly suggest you go and read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: So, how would I be able to update payment info for stripe customer?

Comment: Maybe you could use a singular resource

Answer (score 0):

From your error, :company_id is an object not an integer. Try this,

```
edit_company_payment_path({:company_id => company.id, :payment_id => @payment.id})
```